# Matlab Operator .* to python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

I have found this `.*` matlab operation. What is the similar operation in python?

For example how I can convert this matlab code to python.

```
data.*data_1
```

Comment: `.*` is just  `*` for numpy arrays.

Comment: http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users

Answer (score 6):

In MATLAB, `.*` is [element-wise product](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html):

```
octave:1> data = [1 2 3];
octave:2> data_1 = [4 5 6];
octave:3> data .* data_1
ans =
    4   10   18
```

If you're using Numpy, you could simply write `data * data_1`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = [1, 2, 3]
>>> data_1 = [4, 5, 6]
>>> np.array(data) * np.array(data_1)
array([ 4, 10, 18])
```

Without Numpy, you could use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [i * j for i, j in zip(data, data_1)]
[4, 10, 18]
```